# Selenium grid is not running test on all the nodes

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I have set up the selenium grid with 1 Hub and 10 Nodes. Hub and Nodes are set up on separate VMs having Windows 10 OS. All the nodes registered successfully to Hub and I am able to view them on the Hub URL.

Though all the nodes are registered, I can see only 3 to 4 nodes are getting utilized at a time which increases the test time.

I am using the **selenium-server-4.0.0-prerelease-rc-2-47e47d91fa.jar** and do not set the **--max session** attribute.

Can someone help with the missing piece of setting which I need to do to utilize all the configured nodes?

Comment: can you add the configurations of node and hub for you grid

Comment: I am using below commands to start the hub and node:
         Node:
java -Dwebdriver.edge.driver=msedgedriver.exe -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=chromedriver.exe -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=geckodriver.exe -XX:ActiveProcessorCount=1 -jar selenium-server-4.0.0-prerelease-rc-2-47e47d91fa.jar node --detect-drivers true --max-sessions 1 --publish-events tcp://<hubUrl>:4442 --subscribe-events tcp://<HubUrl>:4443 --host <hostname>
           Hub:
java -jar selenium-server-4.0.0-prerelease-rc-2-47e47d91fa.jar hub --publish-events tcp://<HubUrl>:4442 --subscribe-events tcp://<HubUrl>:4443 --log-level info